# Unknown column in 'field list in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm creating a stored procedure but facing a problem with a field name... when i run the procedure i have an error Unknown column 'pa' in 'field list but i don't understand why...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deletePost`(IN p_id_post INT, IN p_Tbl_ref CHAR(2))
BEGIN

SET @id_post = p_id_post; 
SET @Tbl_ref = p_Tbl_ref;

DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE tbl_ref_product = @Tbl_ref AND id_table = @id_post;

END
```

I have also tried prepared statement...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deletePost`(IN p_id_post INT, IN p_Tbl_ref CHAR(2))
BEGIN

PREPARE STMT FROM 
"DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE tbl_ref_product = ? AND id_table = @id_post";

SET @id_post = p_id_post; 
SET @Tbl_ref = p_Tbl_ref;

EXECUTE STMT USING @Tbl_ref;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

END
```

... but same result... any idea? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: "IN p_Tbl_ref CHAR(2))" perhaps the table is called something like 'pa%'

Comment: no, i've tried also manually with 'pa', same result... :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe makes absolutely no sense based on the procedure definition, so, if you hear the sound of hoofbeats, and you're sure it isn't horses, you might want to check for zebras:

Try `show triggers;`.

The next likely cause is that the procedure is actually working fine, but the table `tbl` has a `BEFORE DELETE` or `AFTER DELETE` trigger defined, and that trigger has a design error, referencing a nonexistent column referred to as `pa`.

Comment: I knew it was a trigger, but I wasn't sure how to figure out what trigger it was. This solved my problem almost immediately, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are using column name as table in delete statement. as table is predefined in sql , it is giving you error. 
try following code

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE deletePost(IN p_id_post INT, IN p_Tbl_ref CHAR(2))
BEGIN

SET @id_post = p_id_post; 
SET @Tbl_ref = p_Tbl_ref;

DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE [table] = @Tbl_ref AND id_table = @id_post;

END`
```

Comment: no, my real column name is not table but tbl_ref_product, that's not the problem... :/